# how to use ffmpeg encrypt AES-128 HLS m3u8 playlist?

Tags: ffmpeg, aes, http-live-streaming

I use the `ffmpeg -i fighter.mp4 -hls_time 10 stream.m3u8` to crated a m3u8 file.
But there's not `#EXT-X-KEY` info in the m3u8 file.
What should I do to add key in the HLS playlist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make use of FFmpeg's HLS segment encryption feature, check out 22.7.1 from [the documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-34).

You may pass the `hls_key_info_file` option, pointing to a file containing the key information. The file may look like:

```
http://server/file.key
/path/to/file.key
```

The first line of this file states the URI for the key, which is written into the HLS playlist. The second line of the file points to the key file (may be local or http) against which the media will be encrypted.

So, adding something like this to your FFmpeg command should work:

`ffmpeg -i fighter.mp4 -hls_time 10 -hls_key_info_file file.keyinfo stream.m3u8`

Comment: I use ffmpeg on mac os x, install it by brew. After running the command, the following error appears: Unrecognized option 'hls_key_info_file'.  How to solve?

Comment: Please provide the full FFmpeg command, and additionally, please run `ffmpeg -version` and tell me what version of the software you are running on your Mac. FFmpeg added support for the `-hls_key_info_file` option in December of 2014, so you will need a recent version of FFmpeg to make this work.